# Sahipro loads the different site when i'm trying to load different page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load a website through sahi by giving the URL in the start URL.But it loading the some other website.

example:
  I'm trying to load http://www.gmail.com but it loads the site which i was recorded previously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start URL in the playback tab of the controller is meant to specify the start URL for the test case you want to play back. If your test script contains the _navigateTo() statement at the first line, it won't matter what start URL you provide. It will just load that start URL and move to playing your script. If you have not included the URL from where you want ot play the scripts, provide the URL as the start URL.

Thanks,